# Is there a reason this is running slow because of how it is coded? Python

Tags: python, performance, runtime

so I have some code here that loops through 10 files in a directory. Each file has perhaps thousands of lines. The code then filters some of the words out of these files line by line. I understand that this can take a while but could my code be improved in some way to make this process faster. Am I making a coding mistake somewhere that causes a bottleneck? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code:

```
import os

def remove_stop_words(string, stopwords_list):
    string_to_list = string.split()
    x = (' '.join(i for i in string_to_list if i.lower() not in (x.lower() for x in stopwords_list)))
    x = x+'\n'
    return x

def get_stop_words_list(stopwords_path):
    with open(stopwords_path, 'r') as f:
        stopwords = f.read().split()
    return stopwords

def main():
    input_location = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/mini_mouse'
    output_location = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/'
    stop_words_path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/NLTK-stop-word-list.txt'
    stopwords = get_stop_words_list(stop_words_path)
    #print(stopwords)

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_location):
        for name in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, name) # joins the new path of the file to the current file in order to access the file
            with open(file_path, 'r') as f: # open the file
                for line in f: # read file line by line
                    x = remove_stop_words(line,stopwords)
                    new_file_path = os.path.join(output_location, name) + '_filtered' # creates a new file of the file that is currenlty being filtered of stopwords
                    with open(new_file_path, 'a') as output_file: # opens output file
                        output_file.write(x) # writes the newly filtered text to the new output file



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Quick look - opening and closing the output file for each line is not particularly efficient.  About how big is `stopwords`?

Comment: Are you concerned with memory usage?

Comment: I agree w/cdarke, you probably want to make x a list that collects all the lines then writes one.  None the less how long could this possibly take?

Comment: Hi guys, stopwords has about 127 words in it. As for my concern with memory usage, yes I think so. At the moment it took a few hours to run through the ten files and filter them. Could that be because of memory?

Comment: Well, I think that cdarke is correct. It sounds like you would be better off streaming the output to a new string as you go along, rather than opening/closing the file for each line.

Comment: make stopwords lower in your get_stopwords function instead of lowering it every iteration

Comment: Make stoowords a set

Comment: How would one go about streaming the output to a new string as you go along? Sorry if that's a stupid question

Comment: Not a stupid question :) I've posted an answer below.

Comment: Combine Chris and Juanpa's suggestions. Make stopwords a set of lowercased stopwords - once. Checking membership in that set would make `remove_stop_words` much faster. If you use the profiler, you would see a lot to time is currently used in that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution for writing file by file, rather than line by line:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_location):
    for name in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, name) # joins the new path of the file to the current file in order to access the file

        filestring = ''
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f: # open the file
            for line in f: # read file line by line
                x = remove_stop_words(line,stopwords)
                filestring+=x
                filestring+='\n' #Create new line

        new_file_path = os.path.join(output_location, name) + '_filtered' # creates a new file of the file that is currenlty being filtered of stopwords
        with open(new_file_path, 'a') as output_file: # opens output file
            output_file.write(filestring) # writes the newly filtered text to the new output file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm getting an error, however, at line ' if i != len(f): # If the last line, don't create newline. ' saying: 'TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()'. Any idea why that might have occured?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is there a problem if each filtered file ends with a new line? Judging by your application, I would imagine this is simplest.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! From several hours down to less than a minute! Thank you! No there isn't a problem with the last line end with a new line. Thank you again :)